# inoremap <up> and <down> interferes with completion selection

Tags: vim

A few months ago I added `inoremap <down> <c-\><c-o>gj` and `inoremap <up> <c-\><c-o>gk` to my vimrc file to facilitate editing files with long lines when `wrap` is set in vim.

With this remapping pressing e.g. `<down>` goes to the next screen line in insert mode regardless of whether it is actually a new line or the same wrapped one.

Today I became aware that this breaks completion selection, i.e. when I type `<CTRL-N>` in insert mode to complete the word I am just typing and there are more than one possible completions a list with those completions is displayed.

Without the remapping I can (as described in `:help popupmenu-keys`) use `<up>` and `<down>` to traverse the list. With the remapping this no longer works.

Is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only insert mode commands containing `<C-\>` are (from `:help index`):

```
|i_CTRL-\_CTRL-N| CTRL-\ CTRL-N go to Normal mode
|i_CTRL-\_CTRL-G| CTRL-\ CTRL-G go to mode specified with 'insertmode'
                CTRL-\ a - z    reserved for extensions
                CTRL-\ others   not used
```

so I'm not sure what that single `<C-\>` is supposed to achieve in your mappings. They do the job perfectly without it:

```
inoremap <Down> <c-o>gj
inoremap <Up>   <c-o>gk
```

Now, the traditional way to work around the issue you describe is to make your insert mode mappings "expression mappings": `:help <expr>`.

```
inoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<C-o>gj"
inoremap <expr> <Up>   pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "\<C-o>gk"
```

So… what happens is that, when you press `<Down>` in insert mode, Vim checks if the completion menu is in use. If yes, then the mapping produces a `<Down>`. If no, the mapping produces whatever you want.

That pattern is often used to override the behavior of `<Tab>` and other keys.

Comment: As a supplement, the `i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O` command is introduced in *insert.txt* (`:h i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O`), like `CTRL-O` but don't move the cursor. The `CTRL-O` command sometimes has a side effect, but in fact, `CTRL-\ CTRL-O` generally only reflects its role in our custom commands. For most of the built-in commands, `CTRL-O` works as expected, even when the cursor is at the end of the line.

Comment: I can't remember where I found the <C-\> remapping, it certainly was not my own idea. Anyway, your solution works perfectly, thanks!